# C and Objective-C: What's the difference between using Float64 and long?

Tags: objective-c, c, types, floating-point, long-integer

What's the difference, in C and Objective-C, between using Float64 and long?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long` is integral (no decimals); `Float64` (or `double`) is floating-point.

Comment: Also note that long is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Long is an integral format, usually on 64bits, but platform-dependant. Float64 is a floating point format, written on 64its (usually double), but guaranteed to be on 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

Like mention before one is a integer and one is a float. The basic difference is the ability to have a decimal point, which a real/float can have and integer can not have. If all things were equal a float is stored in science notation, while an integer is not. A float would allow for a much much bigger number and has no need for being unsigned. A double is a long float, and long is long integer so they are larger values. Also in ANSI C there is no Float64.

Comment: There isn't a "science notation" format for storing binary values. You can't define a word using the same word - the sentence "a long is a long integer" does not make sense.

Comment: @iheanyi In binary scientific notation is represented by use of a sign bit in between the second and first byte. The first byte becomes the exponent. Actually a long is short for a long integer. A long integer uses more bytes than an int(which is short for integer).

Answer (score 0):

Float64 is a floating point number, and long is integral.